# Can't copy text from one div to another (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to replace text in one div with a text from another. Pretty basic stuff, but I'm noob. Can't make it work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var bla = $(."div1").text();
$(".div2").html( bla );
});
```

Comment: Put the `.` in the string!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check browser console, there is a syntax error!

Not

```
$(."div1").text();
```

but

```
$(".div1").text();
```

PoC: http://jsfiddle.net/oj0L8abp/

Comment: still no go http://jsfiddle.net/d8jqsbrm/1/

Comment: You have to load jQuery framrwork in jsfiddle (menu on the left side). Again, check the console :) It'd tell you `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ` meaning jQuery is not loaded. http://jsfiddle.net/d8jqsbrm/2/